# How can i convert mif files to svg using xslt transformation for ArrowHeads

Tags: java, xml, xslt, svg, framemaker

[Expected output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ56A.png) [output generated from xsl transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zy0c.png)

issue : i have marked in red box.

i have converted the mif files with intermediate xml like below for arrowhead.

sample arrowhead : <--

mif:

```
<PolyLine 
   <Unique 1016926>
   <GroupID 12>
   <HeadCap Square>
   <HeadCap ArrowHead>
   <TailCap Square>
   <NumPoints 2>
   <Point  4.89138" 0.28317">
   <Point  4.18741" 0.28317">
  > # end of PolyLine
```

IntermediateXml:

```
<PolyLine>
<Unique keyword="1016926"></Unique>
<GroupID keyword="12"></GroupID>
<HeadCap keyword="Square"></HeadCap>
<HeadCap keyword="ArrowHead"></HeadCap>
<TailCap keyword="Square"></TailCap>
<NumPoints keyword="2"></NumPoints>
<Point keyword=" 440.212460688 25.485696437999998"></Point>
<Point keyword=" 376.856850216 25.485696437999998"></Point>
</PolyLine>
```

2nd sample arrowhead : -->

mif:

```
  <PolyLine 
   <Unique 1016991>
   <GroupID 12>
   <PenWidth  0.7 pt>
   <HeadCap Square>
   <HeadCap ArrowHead>
   <TailCap Square>
   <NumPoints 2>
   <Point  4.18887" 0.53202">
   <Point  4.52617" 0.53202">
  > # end of PolyLine
```

intermediateXml

```
<PolyLine>
<Unique keyword="1016991"></Unique>
<GroupID keyword="12"></GroupID>
<PenWidth keyword=" 0.7 pt"></PenWidth>
<HeadCap keyword="Square"></HeadCap>
<HeadCap keyword="ArrowHead"></HeadCap>
<TailCap keyword="Square"></TailCap>
<NumPoints keyword="2"></NumPoints>
<Point keyword=" 376.988246712 47.88254482800001"></Point>
<Point keyword=" 407.344437192 47.88254482800001"></Point>
</PolyLine>
```

3rd sample arrowhead: 
<-->

mif:

```
<PolyLine 
   <Unique 1016992>
   <GroupID 12>
   <HeadCap Square>
   <HeadCap ArrowHead>
   <TailCap Square>
   <TailCap ArrowHead>
   <NumPoints 2>
   <Point  4.19177" 0.78086">
   <Point  4.52907" 0.78086">
  > # end of PolyLine
```

intermediateXml:

```
<PolyLine>
<Unique keyword="1016992"></Unique>
<GroupID keyword="12"></GroupID>
<HeadCap keyword="Square"></HeadCap>
<HeadCap keyword="ArrowHead"></HeadCap>
<TailCap keyword="Square"></TailCap>
<TailCap keyword="ArrowHead"></TailCap>
<NumPoints keyword="2"></NumPoints>
<Point keyword=" 377.24923975200005 70.278493204"></Point>
<Point keyword=" 407.605430232 70.278493204"></Point>
</PolyLine>
```

For this 3 sample arrowheads i need svg output. below i have tried the svg output but it is not correct.

For <-- arrowhead SVG tried output:

```
<defs>
 <marker id="startarrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="7" refX="-0" refY="3.5" 
 orient="auto">
 <polygon points="10 0, 10 7, 0 3.5" fill="#000000"/>
 </marker>

 <marker id="endarrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="7" refX="8" refY="3.5" 
 orient="auto">
 <polygon points="0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7" fill="#000000"/>
 </marker>
</defs>

<polyline id="line1016926" gid="12" fill="none" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#000000" marker-start="url(#startarrow)" points="440.212460688,25.485696437999998 376.856850216,25.485696437999998"/>
```

Comment: What exactly is not correct?

Comment: The SVG output which i have transformed. it is giving ---> arrow instead <---. the output svg i have used is copied from someother sample arrowhead websites. I dont have the logic behind this transformation.

Comment: This looks like there is some confusion about the meaning of the terms "Head" and "Tail". To me it seems that the head here is the _last_ point of the polyline. `HeadCap keyword="ArrowHead"` then needs to transform to a `marker-end="url(#endarrow)"`, and `TailCap keyword="ArrowHead"` to `marker-start="url(#startarrow)"`

Comment: Thank you. for these two arrowheads(<-- & -->) its been fixed as per you suggestion. But other arrows are not coming as expected. even in some places right and left arrow itself not displayed properly.

Comment: Please check the images i have attached in the topic.